# Unable to connect to my winsock server using external IP

Tags: networking, tcp, winsock, winsock2

When I try to connect to my server using localhost IP or my LAN IP, everything works fine and the client successfully connects.

Problems begin once I attempt to connect to the server using my external IP - I get just `WSAETIMEDOUT` error then and the server can't see any incoming connections.

Canyouseeme.org returns:

```
Error: I could not see your service on <my IP> on port (12345)
Reason: Connection timed out
```

The same thing happens when I try to ping my external IP - I get only `Request timed out`.

I disabled my firewall, my router's firewall, added NAT rule, but I still get the same errors.

My client's code (shortened):

```
SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if(serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("socket() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    return;
}

ZeroMemory(&serverSockAddrIn, sizeof(serverSockAddrIn));

serverSockAddrIn.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "<My external IP>", &serverSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
serverSockAddrIn.sin_port = htons(12345);

if(connect(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverSockAddrIn, sizeof(serverSockAddrIn)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("connect() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(serverSocket);

    return;
}
```

And my server's code (also shortened):

```
SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if(serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
   printf("socket() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

   return;
}

sockaddr_in serverSockAddrIn;

ZeroMemory(&serverSockAddrIn, sizeof(serverSockAddrIn));

serverSockAddrIn.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverSockAddrIn.sin_port = htons(12345);
serverSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if(bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverSockAddrIn, sizeof(serverSockAddrIn)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   printf("bind() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

   closesocket(serverSocket);

   return;
}

if(listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   printf("listen() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

   closesocket(serverSocket);

   return;
}

SOCKET clientSocket;

while((clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
   printf("accept() failed with code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

printf("Client connected\n");
```

Regardless of whether the server is running or not, client's `connect()` keeps returning `10060` => `WSAETIMEDOUT`.

Server calls `accept()` and blocks, since client can't connect.

Note: I run both applications on the same machine, if it matters.

Have you any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: You clearly have a networking issue rather than a coding issue (the code you showed is fine). Your client simply does not have a route to reach the external IP. You should ask about that on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your reply. I also think there's nothing wrong with my code, but it's always better to ask other people, as I couldn't get it to work anyhow. Shall I link this question on Server Fault or just copy it (maybe without the code part, though some people may want to actually see it, thinking it's my fault)?

Comment: A link to this question for reference will suffice, since your new question shoud be about the network setup and not the coding